# how to begin development of application in QT with c# for wince

Tags: windows-ce

i am new in wince developmen and know about c#.net  i want to know about intial steps to begin working on QT with c# for wince  thanks

Answer (score 2):

My bet is that you're navigating uncharted territory here.  There is a desktop project that allows C# to be used with QT [called Qyoto](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Qyoto) but I suspect that it's unlikely anyone has put in the effort to try using it on a device.  You would probably have to pull the source and port it manually. My bet is that just using the Compact Framework, which is already supported under Windows CE, is going to be far less effort.